# invisible border around input field not working

Tags: html, css, input

this is the code to my search bar and button. i am using images as background and would like the input field border to dissappear, however it does not seem to be working

```
.masthead-search input[type=search] {
background: url(http://localhost:6868/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/search-button11.png) no-repeat;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0 10px;
width: 130px;
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

this is my code in the php file for wordpress:

```
<input type="search" class="field" name="s" style="border: 1px #fff;"value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'wpex' ); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two border definitions in your CSS:

```
.masthead-search input[type=search] {
....
border: 1px solid #fff;
...
....
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

and a style applied to your field (which is missing one parameter):

```
<input type="search" class="field" name="s" style="border: 1px #fff;"
```

What shall the browser do? He goes with the last one, probably, which is 1px border.

Comment: oops i just got rid of one border definition, but it still does not seem to be working!

Comment: Go with: `<input type="search" class="field" name="s" style="border:none;"`

Comment: yupp i am trying it, but it still seem to have no effect on my search bar. could the definition be in another location other than these two?

Comment: i think i have found the solution! all the code in my child theme works perfectly when i put it as the original code... so that is what i am going to do, hopefully updates in the future will sustain this operation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  .masthead-search input[type=search] {
background: url("http://localhost:6868/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/search-button11.png") no-repeat;
float: left;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0 10px;
width: 130px;
height: 28px;
line-height: 28px;
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 10px;}
```

Comment: Still two different border definitions in one block?